# Bootloop after editing build.prop via bash

Tags: android, bash, sed

build.prop file is a file that defines a lot of system options and that can be edited as root user on Android. it's placed in /system/build.prop
I edited it via bash from my android app as root user using an android root execution command library (via sed).

The app is used to tweak device, so it modifies some props to make the device better, but after executing sed and the echo the device will bootloop (at net reboot).

```
sed -i '/$prop/d' /system/build.prop
echo $prop=$value >> /system/build.prop
```

This code will generate this output (At the next reboot) https://gist.github.com/AndreaCioccarelli/ad4f90bc4af5a7b24776a87febd4b55b

I don't know, it seems to be related to the SurfaceFlinger and gpu services but i cannot find a link between build.prop and these services.

In this case `$prop` is `net.ipv4.tcp_congestion_control`, while `$value` is `tcp`.

P.S. Using the same exact procedure on /system/etc/sysctl.conf will not have effects.

Nougat 7.0 NEMESIS / Samsung Galaxy S6 Edge / MagiskSU

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem fixed, as you can see:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root u:object_r:system_file:s0 6607 2017-04-30 16:44 build.prop
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root u:object_r:system_file:s0 6643 2017-05-26 14:22 build.prop
```

I changed build.prop permissions from 644 to 664, and it probably thrown an exception spring the system boot, then the device was not able to finish startuo properly

Answer (score 1):

idk about booting, etc. but your shell commands should be quoted properly:

```
sed -i "/$prop/d" /system/build.prop
echo "$prop=$value" >> /system/build.prop
```

as right now `$prop` won't be expanded by your `sed` command since it's within single quotes and both `$prop` and `$value` in the `echo` line are susceptible to word splitting, globbing, file name expansion, etc. since they aren't within any quotes.

See if correcting that fixes your other problem.